# Matplotlib - How to add pie charts to selected years of lineplot

Tags: matplotlib, pie-chart, timeline

Again, I'm kind of lost. 
I try to add pie charts( showing some distribution at the certain time) to the x-axis of a timeline(where I show some meteorological indicators). But I have no idea how to do this... and was searching for quite a while now...

any suggestions?
Many thanks, Veit.

Comment: The functionality to set the center of the a pie-chart _just_ got merged to the master branch yesterday https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/commit/e7717f71abae542ba0a5fea5b072bf52548d5ee3

Comment: lucky me...and thanks a lot for the fast reply. I knwow its probably not the right place here, but I have no idea how to get that running ( sorry). I'm using python2.7(x,y) on windows